# How can a body rotate with no forces acting on it?

Tags: newtonian-mechanics, forces, free-body-diagram, rigid-body-dynamics, centripetal-force

Can a body being acted upon by no force in free space keep rotating, given it was initially rotating?

I feel like it can, however then where does the centripetal force come from?

Am I right in thinking that taking the body as system they cancel, and thus the body can rotate with no force acting?

Note: I am not talking about a couple, but $0$ external force.

Comment: Interestingly, an object can start and stop rotating without external forces! Cats do this to land on their feet.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Yes the body continues rotating indefinitely. See gyroscopes for an example from the real world.

The centripetal force comes from the internal structure of the body which is holding it together. If the body was made from sand and was initially rotating, say in a cast, and the cast was removed then the individual sand grains would fly off in a straight line.

There is an interesting unsolved question called Mach's principle as to how we know that a body is rotating, or what it is rotating with respect to.

Comment: well, different parts of spacetime disagree on what "not rotating" means.

Comment: *or what it is rotating with respect to* - if there's "0 external force" then *you're* not there to observe it, so nothing, and then it's a question of if there's a cat or not? Also, Newton's First Law says so? And what about angular momentum? And... https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mach%27s_principle